# Wrong model appearing in UV editing mode

Tags: modeling, uv

In modelling mode, have no problems - object selected, UV unwraps, ok let me see this in UV editing mode - correct texture on UV window, entirely different object in the 3d window, - have looked/clicked everywhere to fix this, makes no sense

Comment: Can you add more details? Screenshots for instance. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have a scene.
There are numerous objects within the scene.
I've selected one object, and UV unwrapped it.
I then click on the UV editor tab at the top.
The screen then splits into 2D map view on the left and 3D model on the right side.

Except the object in the 3D view is not the correct one, and all the other models are hidden. Cannot unhide all, or activate the correct object.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it - was the local view toggle in UV editing mode, - (the / hotkey)

glad I got out of that rabbithole  :P driving me nuts